# MySQL Consolidating rows in a table belonging to the same id based on condition in one of the columns in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table which collects accounts details for clients. 1 client is allowed to have multiple accounts of different products i.e.

```
id  acc_balances    Product_type
1   2000                 4
1   900                  5
1   1100                 6
2   580                  6
2   70                   5
2   10                   4
```

The following is the desired outcome:

```
id  Product_type_4  Product_type_5  Product_type_6
1   2000                 900             1100
2   10                   70              580
```

Comment: Can you share the query what have you tried so far?

Comment: @arilia thanks a lot for directing me to this resource..... exactly what I was Looking for.          This basically is a pivot table.

A nice tutorial on how to achieve this can be found here: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

I advise reading this post and adapt this solution to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fd969/9)

```
select id,sum(case when product_type = 4
then acc_balances end) as Product_type_4,
sum(case when product_type = 5
then acc_balances end) as Product_type_5,
sum(case when product_type = 6
then acc_balances end) as Product_type_6
from accounts
group by id
```